# output sub select data in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have something like this SQL query which works perfect:

```
SELECT a.id AS thingId
FROM t1 a
JOIN t2 z
ON z.refId = a.id
WHERE z.category IN (
    SELECT y.id 
    FROM t3 x
    JOIN t4 y
    ON x.category = y.id
    WHERE x.id = :a)    
LIMIT 1;
```

But I need a column from the sub select as well, how do I get `x.data` in my output? Unfortunately, `SELECT x.data, a.id AS thingId` does not work.

Comment: You need to join with `t3` in the main query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another `JOIN` rather than `IN`

```
SELECT a.id AS thingId, x.data
FROM t1 AS a
JOIN t2 AS z ON z.refId = a.id
JOIN t4 AS y ON y.id = z.category
JOIN t3 AS x ON x.category = y.id
WHERE x.id = :a
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

join in the main query

```
 SELECT extra.data, a.id AS thingId
    FROM t1 a
    JOIN t2 z
    JOIN t3 extra ON extra.category=z.id
    ON z.refId = a.id
    WHERE z.category IN (
        SELECT y.id 
        FROM t3 x
        JOIN t4 y
        ON x.category = y.id
        WHERE x.id = :a)    
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Your `ON` is in the wrong place, and you need another `ON` for the `t3` join.